# How to set text to QLineEdit when it is used as QItemDelegate with QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qabstracttablemodel

The code below creates a single `QTableView`. An instance of `QAbstractTableModel` is then created and assigned to it as its model. Lastly, the `QItemDelegate` is assigned to the `QTableView`.

The column 0 is being populated with `QLineEdit`. While column 1 is populated with `QComboBox`. 
But even while `QLineEdit` is assigned a custom text value the `QLineEdit` remains to be blank. It doesn't happen with `QComboBox` which properly gets three items: 'Somewhere', 'Over', 'The Rainbow'.

[image]

What should be done to pre-populate column 0 QLineEdits with the text?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Delegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QItemDelegate.__init__(self)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if index.column()==0:
            lineedit=QtGui.QLineEdit(parent)
            lineedit.setText('Somewhere over the rainbow')
            return lineedit
        elif index.column()==1:
            combo=QtGui.QComboBox(parent)
            combo.addItems(['Somewhere','Over','The Rainbow'])
            combo.setCurrentIndex(index.row())
            return combo

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.items = [[1, 'one', None], [2, 'two', None], [3, 'three', None]]

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3 
    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column() 
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.items[row][column]

tableModel=Model()
tableView=QtGui.QTableView() 
tableView.setModel(tableModel)
tableView.setItemDelegate(Delegate())

for row in range(tableModel.rowCount()):
    for column in range(tableModel.columnCount()):
        index=tableModel.index(row, column)
        tableView.openPersistentEditor(index)

tableView.show()
app.exec_()
```

## EDITED LATER:

Big thanks Fabio for the trick.

Working code is posted below.

Instead of handling the value assignment inside of `Delegate.createEditor()` method we should implement `Delegate.setEditorData(editor, index)` instead.
Inside of `setEditorData` we can get both: `index.column()` and `index.row()` as well as to access `self.items` variable used by model using `index` argument `value = index.model().items[row][column]`

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Delegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QItemDelegate.__init__(self)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if index.column()==0:
            lineedit=QtGui.QLineEdit(parent)
            return lineedit

        elif index.column()==1:
            combo=QtGui.QComboBox(parent)
            return combo

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        value = index.model().items[row][column]
        if isinstance(editor, QtGui.QComboBox):
            editor.addItems(['Somewhere','Over','The Rainbow'])
            editor.setCurrentIndex(index.row())
        if isinstance(editor, QtGui.QLineEdit):
            editor.setText('Somewhere over the rainbow')

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.items = [[1, 'one', 'ONE'], [2, 'two', 'TWO'], [3, 'three', 'THREE']]

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3 
    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return 
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return self.items[row][column]

tableModel=Model()
tableView=QtGui.QTableView() 
tableView.setModel(tableModel)
tableView.setItemDelegate(Delegate())

for row in range(tableModel.rowCount()):
    for column in range(tableModel.columnCount()):
        index=tableModel.index(row, column)
        tableView.openPersistentEditor(index)

tableView.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The item delegate set the editor data by `setEditorData` method, that takes the model data and set it to the editor. In this case, the item delegate takes the model data (that maybe is empty) and set it to the `QLineEdit`, so it set an empty string.

If you want to initialize the data in the editor, you have to reimplement `setEditorData`, or initialize the data in your model.

For `QComboBox`, the items are displayed correcly because `setEditorData` doesn't change the items of the combo box. In general you have to reimplement `setEditorData` to set the current index of the combo box depending on the model data.

I suggest to read the documentation: [Model/View Programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) and [Delegate Classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes)